# Send data from phone to wear when app is closed

Tags: android, wear-os

I'm making an app to Android wear, that needs to get information from the app from the smartphone, the problem is that it needs to communicate even if the app on smartphone is closed. Is it possible to implement this? How?

Answer (score 0):

Two options:

1. Start a foreground service from your smartphone app which can communicate with the wear device.
2. You can pause your app by pressing the home button and still manage to send/received data by putting disconnect method in onDestroy method of your smartphone app - not ideal

Comment: I got it working. I used WearableListenerService and a BrodcastReceiver together. (and the Message API) thank you